# Analyzing monthly sex ratio

Tags: chi-squared-test, biostatistics

I have a data something like this. The numbers are the count of identified male and female of fish *Decapterus russelli* (Indian scad). I wanted to know if there's a difference in the sex ratio per month. Is chi-square goodness-of-fit appropriate for this data? If yes, how should I do it? If no, what is the best statistical tool to use?

[image]

I read that binomial test is enough to compare male and female. Here's the link: [How to (properly) analyze the sex ratio](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87008/how-to-properly-analyze-the-sex-ratio). But in my case I have several data, and group per month.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "I wanted to know if there's a difference in the sex ratio per month"? Are you testing if January is different from each subsequent month? Are you testing if the sex ratio is different from 50% each month? Are you trying to see if there is some relationship like, "as the year progresses, it becomes more female"?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to know if the sex ratio is different per month, i.e., if the ratio of male to female changes per month. In addition, if the ratio deviates from the theoretical concept of 1:1 (male:female) ratio.

Comment: One difficulty here might come from the temporal nature of the data. Are the males and females in each month sometimes the same people? So Jim is present for January - Jun and then drops out, while Mary is only present in November and December? Or is each month independent samples of people?

Comment: Aw. Sorry, my mistake. I will edit the question. The data is the count of male and female fish _Decapterus russelli_. Each month is an independent samples of fish.

Comment: No apologies necessary. The only reason I bring that up is that if the same fish (or people or whatever your unit of observation is) are present in each month, you need to somehow account for the fact that measurements from the same subjects are going to be dependent on one another.

Comment: Okay, I get the point. I edited my previous comment. The measurements are from independent samples per month.

Comment: Even if there is independent sampling each month, presumably it is from the same population of fish (a lake?). If these fish lives for more than a few weeks, you will in part sample from the same fish. That will introduce dependency, so you might need some time series model. Also, the month come in time order which the standard chisquare test ignores, so you will need some alternative. Look into time series of counts https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56275/analysis-of-discrete-count-time-series-data.  And, what is life span of  *Decapterus russelli*?

Comment: We did not performed tagging, so the measured fish are all unique individuals. Samples were collected randomly at selected fishing ports.

Comment: @J.Biv The fact that you did not tag the fish does not make the fish unique..(it only means that you cannot tell). If each sample was selected at a different port that would make them unique.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is if the sex ratio of Indian scad deviates from 1 (male = female)?
Ho = 1
Ha # 1
You may calculate the sex ratio for each month and compare it with 1 using one-sample t-test (if data are normally distributed) or one-sample sign test (if data are not normal). If null hypothesis is rejected then there is evidence to conclude that the sex ratio deviated from 1 which also implies the sex ratio each month is different.